# Do you know best practices for refactoring other people's sourcecode?

Tags: refactoring

I have received a bunch of source code from other developers. Source code is not documented and my task is to divide it to different modules. Do you have some approach in your practice how to do it so that the existing application will not be broken.

Comment: Although a bit obvious - you must know exactly what is going on inside the code. If you do, you will be able to divide it into modules without much husstle. If there is even one thing which is not clear to you though, you will probablly end up breaking the app at some point. In other words - Study the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to write test cases for the current part of the code you want to refactor. Writing test cases will also help you to understand what the code really does.

If you have the test code running you can continue with refactoring. Split you code in smaller methods (a method should do only one thing) and follow the clean code principle verifying that the tests are still running.

Then I would start looking for dead and complex code and move methods and classes together that belong together. For this job there are lot of good tools out there that will ease your work. Sonar and dead code detection just to name two.

As the last step I would change the model and find patterns and transform you code accordingly.

The **magic** is to have tested code when you start. Because then you can be pretty sure that your resulting new shiny code behaves the same as before.

Books I can recommend for your task.
Clean Code, Cleaner Code, The Art of Readable Code, Code Simplicity, Quality Code: Software Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns,Head First Design Patterns

Answer (score 2):

Try to establish dependencies between different segments of code. If you see repetition, this is almost certainly a place where you can increase modularity. Additionally, organize things cohesively. Functions in one file should really all serve similar, related purposes. Also, functions in general should usually do small, specialized tasks.

For documentation, I would recommend contacting the developers to ask exactly what they meant. If this is impossible, read, read, and read again. Make sure you understand it inside and out *before* you begin.

Answer (score 2):

I like to establish metrics as goals for the exercise. The problem with refactoring is to know when you're done, and by establishing metrics, you force yourself to think about that.

I use a tool like [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/), integrated with the source code control system and continuous integration pipeline, as a measurement framework. (So, yes, the first things you probably need to do is set up source code control and continuous integration).

The standard Sonar rulesets are pretty sensible. At a high level, you can set goals for unit test coverage and rules compliance. Rules compliance covers all sorts of metrics - code duplication, commented out code, code dependencies, complexity etc.

You can also see graphs of the code's evolution over time, showing you whether you're going in the right direction.

The next bit of "best practice" advice is to capture your work in a task tracking system, as a user story or whatever. In most cases, my business stakeholders want to know when I'm going to be done with the refactoring, and using the same processes I use for tracking feature development helps build confidence.

Finally - while Vadimo's book recommendations are solid, I'd want to add "Refactoring to Patterns". It shows pragmatic steps to improve the code, without necessarily going all the way to "gang of four" purity.